# Nodejs (Next) Cannot import object from module: Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: node.js, next.js, node-modules, module.exports

I have nodejs app using react and nextjs. The most important pieces of the app are kept in the server file.

**main.js**(server file)

```
const app = next({ dev }) //dev = true

...

const DR_LINK = "anything"

module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.DR_LINK = DR_LINK;
```

Now I need the app object for some of my routers.

```
//any router file
const {app} = require("../main")
```

And it works perfectly fine.
But when I try to import the string DR_LINK object

```
import {DR_LINK} from "../main"; 
//not in the same file as the import for app
```

I get this error

```
error - ./node_modules/destroy/index.js:14:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/send/index.js
./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
./node_modules/express/index.js
./main.js
./components/CreateForm.js
./pages/create.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
error - unhandledRejection: OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Declaration` model once compiled.
//for some reason it affects the db models too
```

The export order or exporting it like

```
module.exports = { app, DR_LINK};
```

makes not difference. The app is allways exported but the string object is not. This only happens when app object is exported in any way from the server file. By removing it, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you please show the full code for the file where you're importing `DR_LINK`?

Comment: It looks like one of your packages depends on [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) which it cannot find. Try `npm install` or `npm ci`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up server side and client side code. My guess is you are trying to do`import {DR_LINK} from "../main";` on client side from a server file. The clue is the error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`. This is because `fs` is a built in node.js (server side) package, so your frontend will not know what it is.

I suspect your router files are still server side, hence why the imports (require) work there.

You can define env variables inside next config like so:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables

Or maybe this could also be an option for you as well:

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser